# two textures: painting on one of them while the other is still visible (2.8)

Tags: texture-painting

I have a model with two UVs and two textures: first set is a projected UV with paintover from Photoshop and second UV is a generated UV to paint on top. They're mixed using the Alpha of the second texture.

UVs:

[image]

Textures:

[image]

Result in Lookdev mode:

[image]

I want to be able to paint on the second texture while seeing the first one and sampling colors from both first and second. Is this possible?

At the moment when I switch to paint mode and make several light brush strokes my first texture looks very dark and brushstrokes look like they're opaque. When I switch back to Object mode everything looks like it should.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to turn off overlays in LookDev mode?

Comment: OOOH. Why didn't I try this?? Without overlays it works as expected, thank you! I guess my next question will be how to sample colors from both textures, because by default it samples from the first one and if I turn on sample merged it also samples light...:/

Comment: When you press S to sample, look at the popup there to choose to sample from combined.